# SVG clear and fast using ios native pinch-to-zoom but not with 3d css transforms

Tags: ios, svg

Hi I've run into a very weird issue. Keep in mind this is all using iOS 6.1 mobile safari on an iPad 3.

So I have a large SVG file with around 1500 objects (simple ones like rectangles). If I load this svg file straight into safari it is very fast and responsive. I can pan and pinch to zoom very fast and everything renders crystal clear.

However, this is not sufficient for the website I am creating. I need to be able to load the svg file into a div and still let the user pan and zoom. To do this I added some touch event handlers and animated the svg with 3d CSS transforms. It works very well for panning however, when I zoom into the svg it begins to get pixelated.

This is very confusing because both of these approaches are using hardware acceleration but the latter looks blurry and pixlated while the former does not.

Anybody know why this is and how I can fix it?

Thanks.

FYI this is to how I would pan and zoom the svg:

```
<div style="-webkit-transform: scale3d(4, 4, 1) translate3d(20px, 100px, 0px);">
    <svg version="1.1" width="1024px" height="512px">
        ...
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: When you apply acceleration to the SVG webkit will rasterize it so it can be displayed faster. It effectively becomes a bitmap texture. What you need to do is increase the 'resolution' of that textutre, you can accomplish this by rendering the SVG very large at first, and downsizing via CSS transforms so the "texture" has a higher resolution.

Comment: I was afraid this was the case. Unfortunately I need to render about 5 large (at least 5000x3000 pixels) layers separately which eats up memory fast and can actually crash the iPad.